# socket.io 1.2.1 How to fix double events after reconnect

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

In socket.io's blog says, that in version 1.2.1

> "README fixes to prevent double events in the example upon reconnection [@nkzawa]"

I downloaded 1.2.1 version for client & server, But after reconnect it still call events two times. 
Or I should do something with readme file?

I tried this way  to reconnect and it worked, but can I use it for production. Is it rigth way?

```
socket.disconnect()
// remove socket object
socket = undefined
// connect again
socket = io.connect({'forceNew':true})
```

As I said is it right way or does it have cons?

**UPDATE, added code**

server side code

```
socket.on('client_emited', function(data){
    socketIO.to('this socket id').emit('server_emitted');
})
```

client side code

```
var socket;
function connectSocket () {
   if (!socket)
     socket = io({'forceNew':true});
   else
     socket.connect();
}
socket.on('connect', function(){
   console.log('CONNECTED TO SOCKET.IO SERVER. SENDING "client_emited" EVENT');
   socket.emit('client_emited');
});
socket.on('server_emited', function(){
   console.log('RECEIVED "server_emited" EVENT');
});
socket.connect(); // here console shows 'CONNECTED TO SOCK...' and 'RECEIVED "server_e...' 1 time
socket.disconnect();
socket.connect(); // here console shows 'CONNECTED TO SOCK...' 2 times and 'RECEIVED "server_e...' 4 times time
```

and the server receives "client_emit" event two times

Comment: The problem is likely in the code that creates your message event handlers.  You need to make sure you're only ever calling that code ONCE or you are removing the event handlers before starting new ones.  Please show us that code.

Comment: thank you for response, will show in a minute

Comment: Sir I am correcting code to make understandable, it wil be in 2-3 mins. while could you write your opinion about the second method: first desconnect, remove socket object ren connect again. Can i use it?

Comment: I don't have an opinion about the second method (never tried it myself).  It seems to be a work-around that could have some other consequences and I'd rather you fix the real problem.

Comment: Sir thank you for waiting, I added my code

Comment: jfriend00, I found solution. But thank you for response

Answer (score 10):

The solution is:

```
socket.on('connect', function(){....});
```

change to

```
socket.once('connect', function(){....});
```

For more information read the [issue on github](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/issues/103)